# Remove last three character from ant property

Tags: ant

I have an ant property which has value of the abcdefghijklmn

I want to remove the last three character from the property to abcdefghijk.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

## Example

```
build:
     [echo] x = abcdefghijklmn
     [echo] y = abcdefghijk
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property name="x" value="abcdefghijklmn"/>

  <target name="build">
    <script language="javascript">
      project.setProperty("y", project.getProperty("x").substr(0,11));
    </script>

    <echo message="x = ${x}"/>
    <echo message="y = ${y}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```